# cant run ios simulator on cordova

Tags: ios, macos, cordova-3

On running the command

```
cordova emulate ios
```

I get an error, as below.  I actually get `rm: could not remove` & `permission denied` errors so I use sudo.  I was able to run this no problem, and then after a reboot - although nothing was changed - this function does not work.  After `build succeeded` - `deploying to emulator` I get this error

```
 An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159):
    Invalid device state
    ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/user/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/8F3C9A0F-D432-49A4-84DA-D0480829884A/system.log'
    Error code 1 for command: ios-sim with args: launch,/Users/user/helloworld/platforms/ios/build/emulator/helloworld.app,--devicetypeid,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s,--stderr,/Users/user/helloworld/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--stdout,/Users/user/helloworld/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--exit
    Error: /Users/user/helloworld/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
        at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
        at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
        at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

I have reinstalled `sudo npm install ios-sim -g` and same error.  How can I run it properly?

Comment: Is this happening on El Capitan?

Comment: yes osx 10.11 .  I did a factory reset and its working now.  For now. probably something to do with the setup or old files or something.  But I dont know if there is anything in the error that can be used to find the fix

Answer (score 22):

This happens due to the permissions on mac:

Here are the steps you can use to correct this issue:

Empty the 'platforms' folder in your Cordova project.

Re-run `Cordova platform add ios`, `Cordova build ios`, and `Cordova emulate ios` **without** **sudo**.

If you are on a Mac and are still getting a permissions error, make sure all the files in your user's home folder actually belong to that user by running `sudo chown -R username /Users/username`

Comment: Make sure you restart your terminal application after you run 'sudo chown -R username /Users/username'

Comment: tnx, mine was a permission problem for the files that was created on windows, @Axle it worked for me without restarting the condole :D

Answer (score 1):

Its happening when you don't have simulator configurations for the root user.

Following command worked for me

```
sudo npm install -g ios-sim
```

If it's not working you can try removing platforms as the root user and add it back as normal user.

Answer (score -2):

This happens because xcode command line tools are not installed in your system 
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4657.
Do a xcode-select --install from your terminal and reboot the system should work fine.